# How to know a certain grammar is parse-able

Tags: automata, context-free, parsers, information-theory

Is it possible to parse all kinds of structured data and give them a semantic meaning? For example, C++ is a really complicated language and I could never imagine a parser would be possible for it.

What makes a certain grammar parse-able and contain semantics? How do I decide a written information is parse-able?

Comment: If it were impossible to parse C++, how would it be possible to compile programs written in C++?

Comment: Right, but how do you know before you ever attempt to design?

Comment: Can you define what "parse-able" means for you?  (For instance, under what circumstances would a grammar *not* be parse-able?  How could that happen?)

Comment: The techniques necessary to parse C++ have been known for decades. I suggest taking a class on compilation theory.